# Lines in projective geometry

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

In $\Bbb P^2$, how could I find the equation of the line joining, for example $P =(1:1:0)$ and $Q=(\alpha:0:\beta)$?

I was thinking about $\lambda(1:1:0) + \mu(\alpha:0:\beta)=(\lambda+\mu\alpha:\lambda:\mu\beta)$.

But then the follow up question came...

'Write down the point of intersection of the 2 lines $x+y+z=0$ and $\alpha x+\beta y=0$'. I thought lines in projective space where given by ratios and not really formulas like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the equation of a plane in $k^3$, i.e a line in $\mathbb P^2$. Notice that this equation makes perfectly sense, since it is homogenous : if $(a,b,c)$ verify $a + b + c = 0$ then any equivalent point $(\lambda a, \lambda b, \lambda c)$ will also verify $\lambda a + \lambda b + \lambda c = 0$. 
The value of $x + y + z$ is not defined, but if is is zero or not is, so this makes sense to talk about the line defined by $x + y + z = 0$.

Comment: So if I want to find the point of intersection of those two, I can just solve it like Always with $x+y+z=\alpha x +\beta y$? Not with any special rules or something for projective space?

Comment: Not exactly. For example, if $x + y + z = 1$, this is not true that $\lambda x + \lambda y + \lambda z = 1$. So you can't use inhomogenous equation (i.e you don't want a constant term). 
But what you can do is look at the intersection of the plane $x + y + z = 0$ and $\alpha x + \beta y = 0$. This will give you a line in $k^3$, i.e a point in $\mathbb P^2$.